# UILabel not getting what I write to it

Tags: ios, uilabel

Tricky to write the subject to this. I guess this is a basic question but I can't seem to find the answer.
The code itself shows what I wanna do and the UILabel don't show anything, the first line I add to it works fine, but not when I try to write out the array:

```
-(IBAction)getSongHistory:(id)sender {
[historyLabel setText:@"test write\n test write another line"];
NSArray *pastMusicArray = [pastSongs getHistory];
for(int t=2; t<[pastMusicArray count]; t++) {
    NSString *tempRow = [pastMusicArray objectAtIndex:t];
    //NSLog(@"%@", tempRow);
    [historyLabel setText:tempRow];
    [historyLabel setText:@"\n"];
}
```

}

The NSLog do put out the right stuff.
What is gong on here, that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that the problem is that you are setting the full text each time and the last **setText:** is with @"\n" which is an invisible string. Try appending instead of setting the text. Something like:

```
historyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", historyLabel.text,@"TextToAppend"];
```

This will append @"TextToAppend" to the current text value in the label.

Update: Notice I'm using the text property rather than the setter.

```
historyLabel.text = @"Some Text";
```

is equivalent to

```
[historyLabel setText:@"Some Text"];
```

Comment: The problem was that setText replaces everything in a UILabel hence my last setText was an @"\n". So that meant a blank UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\n` in a string should be fine, try to set `numberOfLines` property of the label to 0, which allow any number of lines in it.

Comment: I did set the numberOfLines to 0 in Interface Builder but that didn't do it until I set in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for my own problem. Hope that it can help someone else.

```
NSArray *pastMusicArray = [pastSongs getHistory];
musicHistory = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
historyLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
for(int t=2; t<[pastMusicArray count]; t++) {
    [musicHistory appendString:[[pastMusicArray objectAtIndex:t] capitalizedString]];
    [musicHistory appendString:@"\n"];
}
historyLabel.text = musicHistory;
```